# Requirments for running my web application under https

Tags: deployment, iis, https

I have created a new web application that uses https. After that I added a new site collection to it, but my question is "will SharePoint web application and the site collection works under HTTPS out of the box? or i need to configure some extra settings ?"

On my development machine I used to add the web application under http but now inside my staging i need to run the SharePoint applications under HTTPS. Should I define special setting under my sharepoint and IIS to allow https?